# Delete button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, git, html-table

Html Table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td>From</td>
            <td>To</td>
            <td>Add</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_clone">
            <td><input type="text"  placeholder="who" name="who" /></td>
            <td><input type="text"  placeholder="location" name="location" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table><!-- /table#table-data -->
```

Javascript:

```
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

function deleteRow(r)
{
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("table-data").deleteRow(i);
}
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep/b6A9R/

This code is cloning first two cells of a table row. I have add and delete button for every row.

I want this as like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/5/

Add button wants to be there for the cloning row and delete button should be there for the cloned row.

I want to include the functionality while cloning first two cell values has to come to the cloned row?

Let me know if you have doubts in this question.

Comment: So what's your _actual_ problem here? The only difference I can see between your JSFiddle and the correct example you posted is that the add/delete buttons are never shown next to each other. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood by your question, on that basis I have created [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYaHd/5/). Hope it will help you,except the default value case.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYaHd/7/)

To delete row, you can try:

```
var $actualrow = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
$actualrow.remove();
```

Comment: Thankyou.hi your answer perfectly for me.Can i know how i can currently it is cloning entire row with values .I need entire row clone with first two column values and remaining it should be blank to enter manually.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>`

The problem is, where is your `deleteRow()` ? it's not in your fiddle..

fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/b6A9R/5/

and you have to change `onLoad` to `No wrap`, otherwise your function will not work.

Comment: hi only cloned row have delete button not on cloning row.i can able to delete  first not the other rows .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code for `onLoad`.

JS

```
 $(document).on('click','input[value="Delete"]',function(){
    deleteRow(this);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/277xQ/)

Comment: hi only cloned row have delete button not on cloning row